# RSA smaller number work-out-by-hand not working - I think I made a mistake

Tags: rsa, public-key, modular-arithmetic

I tried out the paper/pencil explanation [here](https://sergematovic.tripod.com/rsa1.html), and it seemed to make sense just fine until I came to decryption. Here is what I worked out:

## Key Creation:

Choose two different prime numbers *p* and *k*:

```
p = 23
k = 29
```

Find *n* by calculating `p * q`:

```
n = 23 * 29
n = 667
```

Find *z* by calculating `(p - 1) * (q - 1)`:

```
z = (23 - 1) * (29 - 1)
z = 22 * 28
z = 616
```

Pick a number *k* that is coprime to *z*:

```
616 % 2 != 0
616 % 3  = 0
k = 3
```

The public key consists of *n* and *k*:

```
Public Key:
n = 667
k = 3
```

Find a number *j* where `(k * j) % z = 1`:

```
(3 * 411) % 616 = 1
j = 411
```

*j* is the secret key:

```
Private Key:
j = 411
```

## Encryption:

Public key from earlier:

```
Public Key:
n = 667
k = 3
```

Choose a number *p* to encrypt (with the obvious requirement that it be smaller than the modulus *n*):

```
p = 13
```

Find the encrypted result *E* by calculating `E = (p ^ k) % n`:

```
(13 ^ 7) % 667 = 492
E = 492
```

## Decryption:

Public Key:

```
Public Key:
n = 667
k = 3
```

Private Key:

```
Private Key:
j = 411
```

Encrypted Result:

```
Encrypted Integer:
E = 492
```

Recover the integer *p* by calculating `p = (E ^ j) % n`

```
(492 ^ 411) % 667 = 144
p = 144
```

## ?:

Now here is the issue: I input 13 as *p* and recovered 144 instead. At first I thought I had messed up the modexp part, but I got the same results when using information from the University of Minnesota modexp calc.

So did I mess up somewhere, were the original instructions wrong, and/or something else?

And more importantly, if I messed up, where did I mess up and which instruction(s) is/are wrong if the instructions were wrong?

Any help is appreciated.

PS: Yes, I understand that the key size is way too small to be secure IRL; however, I just wanted to learn how the algorithm works.

Comment: During encryption, the public exponent `3` turned into a `7`.

Comment: In the Key Creation step, when you wrote `616 % 2 != 0` and `616 % 3  = 0`, didn't you mean to reverse those with regards to which is `!=` and which is `=` ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

At the encryption step, you wrote:

```
Public Key:
n = 667
k = 3

Input:
p = 13

Encrypted Integer:
E = (p ^ k) % n
```

And then mistakenly calculated:

```
(13 ^ 7) % 667 = 492
______^_____________
```

If you calculate it right using `k = 3`, you will get `E = 196` which correctly decrypts to `13`.

(as expected)

Comment: I can't believe I missed that. After checking it does work out, though. Thanks!